# Random en un retorno de una función

Tags: javascript

En un fichero tengo los texto de las Faqs y en otro gestiono este mismo fichero para separar texto de código

Lo que intento es que cuando se escoja la pregunta 0 nos devuelva una pregunta y respuesta aleatoria, cuando es una pregunta no hay problema, pero cuando es una respuesta no se como hacerlo ya esta es una función con parámetros y nos retorna un array de posibles respuestas.

Me gustaría saber como se puede solucionar esto sin tener que alterar el array faq del principio
y ya de paso no se si quedarme con la opción de clases o con la de función a secas o cualquier otra que me comentéis.

```js
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
FILE 1
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const pizzas = { p:"piña", v:"verdura", t:"ternera", s:"salmón" };

let faq = 
    [
        [ // 0
            // preguntas
            [ "¿Qué te gusta más?",
              "¿Qué pizza prefieres?",
              "¿333333?",
              "¿444444?"
            ],
            // respuestas
            (p) => {
                if (p) {
                    return ["Me gusta mucho la pizza de " + pizzas[p],
                            "Me chiflan las pizzas de " + pizzas[p],
                            "Tengo pasión por la pizza de " + pizzas[p]];  
                } else {
                    return ["Me gustan todas por igual.",
                             "No sabria decirte"];
                }
            }
        ],
        [ // 1
            // preguntas
            [ "¿Hay algo que no te guste?",
              "¿Qué pizzas le tienes grima?",
              "¿Qué pizza no te gusta?",
              "¿Qué pizza odias?"
            ],
            // respuestas
            (p) => {
                if (p) {
                    return ["Siempre he odiado la pizza de " + pizzas[p],
                            "Odio las pizzas de " + pizzas[p],
                            "Las pizzas de " + pizzas[p] + " son asquerosas"];  
                } else {
                    return ["Me gustan todas por igual.",
                             "No sabria decirte"];
                }
            }
        ]
    ]

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
FILE 2
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// forma 1 usando una clase
class Faq {
    constructor(faq) {
        this.faq = faq.map(function(index, elem) {
            return {
                usado: false,
                preg : index[0][Math.floor(Math.random()*index[0].length)],
                resp : index[1] // retorna array pero quiero solo una elección aleatoria
            }
         });
        return this.faq;
    }
}

// forma 2 con una función
faq2 = function(faq) {
    let f = faq.map(function(index, elem) {
        return {
            usado: false,
            preg : index[0][Math.floor(Math.random()*index[0].length)],
            resp : index[1] // retorna array pero quiero solo una elección aleatoria
        }
     });
    return f;
}

// uso
let f1 = new Faq(faq);
let f2 = faq2(faq);
console.log("pregunta like: ",f1[0].preg);
console.log("pregunta dislike: ",f1[0].resp('t'));
console.log("pregunta like: ",f2[0].preg);
console.log("pregunta dislike: ",f2[0].resp('t'));
```

Comment: Justo encima de donde tienes `resp`, estas obteniendo una pregunta aleatoria del array que te retorno, ¿No te funciona usar el mismo metodo que usas justo una linea arriba?

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido Seria lo lógico pero si te fijas `index[0]` es un array y `index[1]`  es una función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que devuelve una función, podemos simplemente devolver una función que se encargue de llamar a esa función y sacar una respuesta aleatoria:

```
class Faq {
    constructor(faq) {
        this.faq = faq.map(function(index, elem) {
            return {
                usado: false,
                preg : index[0][Math.floor(Math.random()*index[0].length)],
                resp : t => {
                    const respuestas = index[1](t)

                    return respuestas[Math.floor(Math.random()*respuestas.length)]
                }
            }
        });

        return this.faq;

    }
}
```